# Yii relations with limit

Tags: yii

Здравствуйте, есть следующие связи:

```
    public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'products' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Products', 'product_category(categoryid, productid)'),
        'parent' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Categories', 'parentid'),
        'childs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Categories', 'parentid', 'order' => 'childs.name', 'with'=>'products'),
    );
}
```

Конкретно интересует следующая строка

```
 'childs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Categories', 'parentid', 'order' => 'childs.name', 'with'=>'products'),
```

with=>products как сделать limit 10?

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, также, как и `order`

```
'childs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 
                 'Categories', 
                 'parentid', 
                 'order' => 'childs.name', 
                 'limit' => 10,
                 'with'=>'products'),
```

либо уже на месте

```
$model->products(array('limit' => 10));
```